# PHPFastCache works on Localhost not on live server

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I am total newbie with phpfastcache library but I get it to work on localhost (XAMMP) but not on my live server.

The code is the following

```
<?php
    require_once("./phpfastcache/phpfastcache.php");

    $prices=phpFastCache() ;
    $store_euro=$prices->get("store_euro_price"); 

    if ($store_euro_price==null){
        $store_euro=getPriceFromDBeuro("store");
        $prices->set("store_euro_price",$store_euro,600);
    }
    echo $store_euro;
?>
```

It just won't load any prices either from db or cache... Any ideas?

Comment: Dont you have to have one of `apc or xcache or memcache or memcached or wincache` activated on the PHP instance before this will work. Have you checked your Host has at least one of these activated?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't have any of what you mentioned installed on localhost (or I didn't find it) and phpfastcache worked. I checked my host and found that it has enabled the memcache. Should phpfastcache work?

Comment: What does your config for fastcache look like.

Comment: Take a look here, its pretty default, I didn't change anything. http://pastebin.com/xANYJxfU

Comment: Then you are probably using the `files` cache mechanism..... why bother. Anyway check this parameter in the config  `"path" =>  "" , // default path for files` make sure its pointing to something that exists on the hosting server

Comment: Could you poing me somewhere about why files cache mechanism is bad? I did check the parameter and set it up to something that does exist nothing changed :/

Comment: Didnt say it was bad, but basically you are doing a file access instead of a database access. Not sure what the difference would be but I would bet its not much, certainly not 1000 times faster as they are suggesting on their website. Only benefit would be if your host limited you to 500 queries an hour, and if they do, ditch them, or you were planning to move to a site that allowed a real caching mechanism and phpfastcache would then pickup and use it supposedly automatically.

Comment: I use a remote db as I am in a free plan, I just do a project for myself. Using phpfastcache I got 300% speed upgrade which is quite nice. That's why I wanted to use it. Anyway I guess I will have to change and use memcache instead. Thanks for your comments @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well that explains why you are using it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly any idea how can I hide the memstats that block my page?